# SQL Azure test database transfer every night

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a test database in SQL Azure, and I'd like to restore the live database (SQL Azure) on to it at 3am each day, over writing all the data so as the test database becomes a copy of the previous days data.

What is the best practice for doing this inside of Azure?

Comment: No, not yet...  :-(

Do you have one?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database always creates a new database when restoring. Because of this you would not be able to restore into an existing database, however you could create a new database using restore, then later delete it when you are ready to create the new day's restored database.

One approach for accomplishing this would be to leverage [Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/).
If you go this route you will first need to configure an automation account and set up a runbook to run a workflow. Here are the steps:

1. Set up Azure Automation Account and Runbook. See guide here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/
2. After you setup the automation account you will want to create a runbook and PowerShell workflow to run the task. Here is a workflow sample of restoring a database to a copy: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Azure-SQL-Database-Daily-cbd4f15d
3. After you save and publish this runbook on your account, setup a schedule for it. This can be done by just selecting the runbook's schedule tab in the portal.

Hope this helps!